# Tuleap - SVN checkout issue - 403 forbidden

Tags: svn, tuleap

I'm using the latest version of Tuleap. Due to some security issues in my organization, I have recently changed the hostname of Tuleap (i.e.,from **alm.india.com** to **alm.bank.net**). I have everything working in common except the repository access from Subversion. When I try to checkout, it is showing the following error:

> Error Code: 403 Forbidden. The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator. (12202).

Our admin side couldn't able to resolve this issue. We have checked with both the http and https connection mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't fully change the host name everywhere in the config. ALL instances of "alm.india.com" need to be replaced in

/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc or /etc/codendi/conf/local.inc (depending on your OS version)

and /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (look for svn).

Similar questions on the website might also have potential solutions.

Comment: i did the changes in both the local.inc and httpd.conf file, but the issue still persists, has i missed out some other changes?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue several times and coulnd't solve it, svn checkout commandline tool and TortoiseSVN both give 403 Forbidden when I checkout my project.

But interestingly RapidSVN (http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) could checkout the project, then I upgrade the working copy using TortoiseSVN and use it normally.